# Comma delimited file contain comma in value

Tags: awk, csv

I have a file with data as below:

```
“A”,”Dept1”,”i am mahesh,working in it”,”1”
“B”,”Dept2”,”i am suresh, working in non it”,”2”
```

Output i want is:

```
A,Dept1,i am mahesh~working in it,1
B,Dept2,i am suresh~working in non it,2
```

I have tried below but it is replacing all , with ~ as below:

```
awk -F ‘“,”’ -v OFS=‘’ ‘{for (i=0;i<=NF;++i) gsub(“,”,”~”,$i)}1’ file

“A”~”Dept1”~”i am mahesh~working in it”~”1”
“B”~”Dept2”~”i am suresh~working in non it”~”2”
```

Comment: Can you confirm your data actually uses `“` over `"`?

Comment: Sorry for typo, it’s normal double quotes only.

Comment: John please fix your data so it matches reality. In particular, the "smart" quotes (double and single). It's unreasonable to expect us to guess what your data actually looks like

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the poster still hasn't fixed their data and has seemingly abandoned the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `sed` and a) change all occurences of a comma NOT between double quotes to tilde, then b) remove all double quotes:

```
sed 's/\([^"]\),\([^"]\)/\1~\2/g;s/"//g' infile
```

Use `-i` to replace the file inplace if the results are fine.

Assumption is that **all** fields are enclosed in quotes before usage.

Comment: It also assumes there are no embedded double quotes next to an internal comma, and that the embedded commas are not first or last within the quoted field.

Comment: `sed -i ...` does not edit the file in-place.  It creates a temporary file, then renames the temporary file to the original name, **deleting the original file**.

Answer (score 1):

When working with structured document formats, use tools aware of that particular format, not generic text-processing tools.

In a CSV file, unless it's known to be "simple", quoted fields may contain commas and newlines.  Quotes within quoted fields are doubled up (`""`).

To change the embedded commas into tilde (`~`), you ideally use a CSV-aware tool such as [mlr](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (Miller) or [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Below, I'm assuming that the quoting character is the ordinary double quote (`"`), not the curly quotes you're using in the question text (`”`).

This is transforming the 3rd field with `mlr`, which is a handy tool that is aware of several different structured formats:

```bash
$ mlr --csv -N put '$3=sub($3,",","~")' file
A,Dept1,i am mahesh~working in it,1
B,Dept2,i am suresh~ working in non it,2
```

The `--csv` option causes `mlr` to input and output CSV data, and `-N` tells the utility that our data has no header.  We then apply the `put` "verb" (action) and give it an expression that ought to be looking familiar if you're used to `awk` (the order of the arguments to `sub()` is different, though).

---

With `csvformat` (from csvkit), we can reformat the data so we may more easily get to the commas we want to change.

I'm first changing the delimiters to `@` (any character that is not already part of the data):

```bash
$ csvformat -D '@' file
A@Dept1@i am mahesh,working in it@1
B@Dept2@i am suresh, working in non it@2
```

I may then simply use `tr` to change the remaining commas to tilde:

```bash
$ csvformat -D '@' file | tr ',' '~'
A@Dept1@i am mahesh~working in it@1
B@Dept2@i am suresh~ working in non it@2
```

Then switch back the delimiters to commas using `csvformat` again:

```bash
$ csvformat -D '@' file | tr ',' '~' | csvformat -d '@'
A,Dept1,i am mahesh~working in it,1
B,Dept2,i am suresh~ working in non it,2
```

Note that this changes *all* embedded commas to tilde, not just the commas in the third column.

Redirect the result to a new name to save it to a file.

Comment: Hi Kusalananda, i have not tried csvkit tool because i have some limitations and do not have package installed for csvformat command and i am getting error as ‘command not found’. So i was using awk utility. Please help me using sed/awk.

Comment: @John In that case, you will have to implement at least a partial CSV parser in `awk` or `sed`.  I will not do this here.  Your other option is to wait for another answer that better fits your needs.

Comment: @John I added another solution using another CSV-aware tool called `mlr`.